# Packets getting dropped - triangle topo network

Tags: python, networking, routes, packet

This code is supposed to be recreating the network shown by the diagram attached, however when I run the command 'pingall', this is the result:

> r1 -> X r3 X X X
>
> r2 -> r1 r3 X X X
>
> r3 -> r1 X X X X
>
> h1 -> r1 X r3 X X
>
> h2 -> r1 X r3 X X
>
> h3 -> r1 X r3 X X
>
> *** Results: 66% dropped (10/30 received)

Why are most of my packets getting dropped? I believe all the links and routing is correct but perhaps I've misunderstood something, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call

def myNetwork():

    net = Mininet( controller=Controller, topo=None, build=False, ipBase='0.0.0.0/0')
    net.addController('c0')

    # Add routers
    info( '*** Add routers\n')
    r1 = net.addHost('r1', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r1.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
    r2 = net.addHost('r2', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r2.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
    r3 = net.addHost('r3', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r3.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')

    # Add hosts
    info( '*** Add hosts\n')
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', cls=Host, ip='10.0.1.1/24', defaultRoute='via 10.1.1.3')
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', cls=Host, ip='10.0.2.1/24', defaultRoute='via 10.1.2.6')
    h3 = net.addHost('h3', cls=Host, ip='10.0.3.1/24', defaultRoute='via 10.1.3.27')

    # Add Links
    info( '*** Add links\n')
    net.addLink(h1, r1)
    net.addLink(h2, r2)
    net.addLink(h3, r3)
    net.addLink(r1, r2)
    net.addLink(r1, r3)
    net.addLink(r2, r3)

    # Start the network
    info( '*** Starting network\n')
    net.build()
    info( '*** Starting controllers\n')
    for controller in net.controllers:
        controller.start()

    # Set IP addresses on router interfaces
    info( '*** Post configure switches and hosts\n')

    r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth0 inet 10.1.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth1 inet 10.1.7.2 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth2 inet 10.1.9.2 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth0 inet 10.1.3.27 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth1 inet 10.1.7.1 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth2 inet 10.1.8.2 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r3.cmd('ifconfig r3-eth0 inet 10.1.2.6 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r3.cmd('ifconfig r3-eth1 inet 10.1.9.1 netmask 255.255.255.0')
    r3.cmd('ifconfig r3-eth2 inet 10.1.9.2 netmask 255.255.255.0')

    info( '*** Adding static routes\n')
    r1.cmd('ip route add 10.1.9.1/24 via 10.1.9.2 dev r1-eth1')
    r1.cmd('ip route add 10.1.7.1/24 via 10.1.7.2 dev r1-eth2')
    r3.cmd('ip route add 10.1.9.2/24 via 10.1.9.1 dev r3-eth0')
    r3.cmd('ip route add 10.1.8.2/24 via 10.1.8.1 dev r3-eth1')
    r2.cmd('ip route add 10.1.7.2/24 via 10.1.7.1 dev r2-eth0')
    r2.cmd('ip route add 10.1.8.1/24 via 10.1.8.2 dev r2-eth1')

    # Run CLI
    CLI(net)

    # Shutdown the topology when user exits the CLI
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    myNetwork()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the top router is R1, the one on the left is R3 and the one to the right is R2, is this correct?

Comment: @coderboy99 Yes that's right!